# Blazor server side - How to select camera and snap a picture

Tags: javascript, camera, blazor-server-side

I have looked at all the examples I could find but cannot find an example that does both, select camera (front or rear) and snap an image.

How can I add to the example below the ability to select a different camera.

https://github.com/mdwaseelahmed/WebCamjsBlazorDemo

[wwwroot/webcamjs/Configuration.js]

```
    function ready() {
    if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
        Webcam.set({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 90
        });
        try {
            Webcam.attach('#camera');
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
}

function take_snapshot() {
    // take snapshot and get image data
    var data = null;
    Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {

        data = data_uri;
    });
    return data;
}
```

[wwwroot/webcamjs/webcam.js]

I cannot add this file because it pushes over the body limit.

[_Host.cshtml]

```
@page "/"
@namespace WebcamjsDemo.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>WebcamjsDemo</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="WebcamjsDemo.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/webcamjs/webcam.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/webcamjs/Configuration.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Index.razor]

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button @onclick="Capture">Capture</button>

<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Camera</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="camera"></div>
            <!-- A button for taking snaps -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Captured Photo</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>

@foreach (var item in stringList)
{
    <img src="@item" alt="Alternate Text" width="200px;" height="200px;" />
}



@code
{
    List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
    string aa = "";
    public async void Capture()
    {
        stringList.Add(await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("take_snapshot"));
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ready", this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the InputFile component. This one allows you to specify to use the camera, which will then trigger the native camera app where you can switch between both cameras.

```
<InputFile accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg;capture=camera" OnChange="HandleFileSelected" />
```

capture=camera is the important part of this code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Webcam.set({
            width: 700,
            height: 350,
            dest_width: 640,
            dest_height: 480,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 75,
            force_flash: false,
            constraints: {
                facingMode: 'environment'
      }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).